# How to find out specific python error?

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing the following classifier to check out sci-kit.

...

```
class MyClassifier():
    def fit(self, x_train, y_train):
        self.x_train = x_train
        self.y_train = y_train
        return

    def predict(self, x_test):
        prediction = []
        for row in x_test:
            label = self.closest(row)
            prediction.append(label)
        return prediction

    def closest(self, row):
        best_dist = euc(row, self.x_train[0])
        best_index = 0
        for i in range(1, len(self.x_train)):
            dist = euc(row, self.x_train[0])
            if dist < best_dist:
                best_dist = dist
                best_index = i
        return self.y_train[best_index]
```

And later, I want to use my own classifier:

```
# Use my own Classifier
classifer = MyClassifier()
print(classifer)
classifer = classifer.fit(x_train, y_train)
prediction = classifer.predict(x_test)
print(prediction)
print(y_test)
```

When I run it, I am getting the following error:

```
<__main__.MyClassifier object at 0x103ec5668>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.../NewClassifier.py", line 72, in <module>
    prediction = classifer.predict(x_test)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'predict'
```

What's wrong with predict() function?

Answer (score 3):

Your classmethod

```
def fit(self, x_train, y_train):
    self.x_train = x_train
    self.y_train = y_train
    return
```

returns nothing, so it implicitly returns `None`.

Therefor `classifer = classifer.fit(x_train, y_train)` is overwrites the variable named `classifer` of type `MyClassifier` wiht a `None`.

A `None` has not method that you can call - thats the exact error message you got.

You should change `classifer = classifer.fit(x_train, y_train)` to simply

```
classifer.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

so you keep the variable named `classifer` as your Class-Instance instead of "overwriting" it with `None`.

---

This should fix it:

```
# Use my own Classifier
classifer = MyClassifier()
print(classifer)
classifer.fit(x_train, y_train)
prediction = classifer.predict(x_test)
print(prediction)
print(y_test)
```

Comment: Darn it, you beat me to the punch :(

Comment: Got it! My silly mistake, after making this small fix, I had to make another typo to fix this code, but it is working now!

Comment: @user9524761 Give  [How to debug small programs (#1)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) a read - it helps you to help yourself. Good that it works for you now.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using Python's built in debugger, pdb.  If you add `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()` before your `classifer = MyClassifier()` statement, you can see every variable and interact with your code.

Now, you are overwriting your class instantiation.

```
-> print(classifer)
(Pdb) n
<__main__.MyClassifier object at 0x7f7fe2f139e8>  // This is your classifer object
-> classifer = classifer.fit("test", "test2")
(Pdb) classifer
-> prediction = classifier.predict(x_test)
(Pdb) classifer
(Pdb)
```

So, because you are naming the variable the same thing, it's overwriting your previous class.

You have `classifer = MyClassifier()` and then `classifer = classifer.foo` so, it loses it's orginal reference to `MyClassifier()`.

Secondly, your `fit(x_train, y_train)` function doesn't return anything.

Having:

```
def fit(self, x_train, y_train):
        self.x_train = x_train
        self.y_train = y_train
        return
```

Is the same as:

```
def fit(self, x_train, y_train):
        self.x_train = x_train
        self.y_train = y_train
        return None
```

Which is what your getting:

```
(Pdb) print(classifer)
None
```

And thus, that's why your receiving `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'predict'` because `classifer` is None.

I'm not sure what the fit function is supposed to return, but I imagine it's self.  So, the following code works for me in getting past your error, but since i don't know what x_train, y_train, x_test, and y_test are supposed to be, I couldn't run all of your code.  Still, it fixes the problem you asked the question about.

```
class MyClassifier():
    def fit(self, x_train, y_train):
        self.x_train = x_train
        self.y_train = y_train
        return self  // Must return something, and from context, this
                     // seems to be your intention.

    def predict(self, x_test):
        prediction = []
        for row in x_test:
            label = self.closest(row)
            prediction.append(label)
        return prediction

    def closest(self, row):
        best_dist = euc(row, self.x_train[0])
        best_index = 0
        for i in range(1, len(self.x_train)):
            dist = euc(row, self.x_train)
            if dist < best_dist:
                best_dist = dist
                best_index = i
        return self.y_train[best_index]

classifier = MyClassifier()
print(classifier)
classifier2 = classifier.fit("test", "test2")
prediction = classifier2.predict(x_test)
print(prediction)
print(y_test)
```

Comment: Still a nice answer - lets see who gets more upvotes ;) +1